# Why doesn't phonegap embed it's own webview?

Tags: browser, cordova, webkit, v8

Why doesn't phonegap bundle webkit and V8 into builds instead of relying on the webviews provided by the OS?

Answer (score 0):

iOS does not let you deploy an external interpreter/compiler. Therefore you are limited to the OS's builtin WebView.